Convert unitless numbers to real units
is there a way to convert some unitless numbers to real world units? Like the damping setting for cloth simulations don’t use any real units and is just a number while in real like it’s in kpa so is there a way to do the math of what something like 100kpa equals in the unitless number that blender uses? (Like 100kpa = 0.5 damping for example)

You could look through the source code for the relevant feature (i believe it's located approximately here) and see if there's any explanation for the units you're looking for thats not shown in the UI.

I don’t think I’m smart enough to understand that
